# Getting this error Android.Views.InflateException: Loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am getting an error but do not know why. The first block of code causes this error at line 23. But I have a Main_Screen.axml file so I do not know why this is happening. I looked up the error and it says I have something wrong in the .axml file. It may be a simple error I am overlooking because it looks fine to me.

```
using ...
...

namespace DM_App_Code_Fragment
{
    [Activity(Label = "DM_App_Code_Fragment", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainScreen : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main_Screen);

            Button show_quick_timer = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
            show_quick_timer.Click += delegate
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(QuickTimer.QuickTimer));
            };

            var show_new_recipe = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            show_new_recipe.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //StartActivity(typeof(CreateNewScreen));
            };

            var show_load_recipe = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);
            show_load_recipe.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //StartActivity(typeof(LoadRecipeScreen));
            };

            var show_view_running_timers = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button5);
            show_view_running_timers.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //StartActivity(typeof(ViewRunningTimersScreen));
            };

        }

    }

}
```

This is the .axml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60.0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40.0dp"
        android:text="Timer App" />
    <Button
        Click=""
        android:text="Quick Timer"
        android:layout_width="310.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100.0dp" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/space1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Create New"
        android:layout_width="310.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="150.0dp" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/space2" />
    <Button
        android:text="Load"
        android:layout_width="310.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="200.0dp" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/space3" />
    <Button
        android:text="View Running Timers"
        android:layout_width="310.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="250.0dp" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/space4" />
    <Button
        android:text="Exit"
        android:layout_width="310.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginTop="300.0dp" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/space5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the error stack:

```
04-20 21:28:16.076 I/MonoDroid(  510): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
04-20 21:28:16.076 I/MonoDroid(  510): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:895
04-20 21:28:16.076 I/MonoDroid(  510): at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:3243
04-20 21:28:16.076 I/MonoDroid(  510): at DM_App_Code_Fragment.MainScreen.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in c:\Users\JD\Desktop\DM_App_Code_Fragment __\DM_App_Code_Fragment v.03\DM_App_Code_Fragment\DM_App_Code_Fragment\Main_Screen.cs:23
04-20 21:28:16.076 I/MonoDroid(  510): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1559
04-20 21:28:16.076 I/MonoDroid(  510): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.6f0ff6a7-86fe-4c4c-9c83-f8e6b79d1576 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
04-20 21:28:16.076 I/MonoDroid(  510):
```

Comment: What is the text of the error message?

Comment: The answer lies in your xml design file. Look there for something that is invalid line of code.

Comment: As it turns out one of my team mates had something called "Space" in the axml file that I had to comment out.